# Intranet File exchange app using Titanium Desktop

Tags: titanium

Is it possible to create a app using Titanium Desktop to transfer files between users
in the intranet.

They  also provide support for Ruby. My question is that can we use all the functionality provided by Ruby like the sockets,files etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. My understanding is that for desktop apps you can use all of the features of Ruby.

(You may have figured this out by now)